# Fastest possible way to create a Swift Array<Float> with a fixed count

Tags: arrays, swift, optimization, unsafemutablepointer

I noticed that this:

```
let a = [Float](repeating: 0, count: len)
```

takes very significantly more time than just

```
let p = UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>.allocate(capacity: len)
```

However, the unsafe pointer is not so convenient to use, and one may want to create a `Array<Float>` to pass onto other code.

```
let a = Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: p, count: len))
```

But doing this absolutely kills it, and it is faster to just create the `Array` with zeros filled in.

Any idea how to create an `Array` faster and at the same time, have an actual `Array<Float>` handy? In the context of my project, I can probably deal with the unsafe pointer internally and wrap it with `Array` only when needed outside the module.

**Quick test on all the answers in this post:**

```
let len = 10_000_000

benchmark(title: "array.create", num_trials: 10) {
    let a = [Float](repeating: 0, count: len)
}

benchmark(title: "array.create faster", num_trials: 10) {
    let p = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Float>.allocate(capacity: len)
}

benchmark(title: "Array.reserveCapacity ?", num_trials: 10) {
    var a = [Float]()
    a.reserveCapacity(len)
}

benchmark(title: "ContiguousArray ?", num_trials: 10) {
    let a = ContiguousArray<Float>(repeating: 0, count: len)
}

benchmark(title: "ContiguousArray.reserveCapacity", num_trials: 10) {
    var a = ContiguousArray<Float>()
    a.reserveCapacity(len)
}
benchmark(title: "UnsafeMutableBufferPointer BaseMath", num_trials: 10) {
    let p = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Float>(len) // Jeremy's BaseMath
    print(p.count)
}
```

Results: (on 10 million floats)

array.create: 9.256 ms

array.create faster: 0.004 ms

Array.reserveCapacity ?: 0.264 ms

ContiguousArray ?: 10.154 ms

ContiguousArray.reserveCapacity: 3.251 ms

UnsafeMutableBufferPointer BaseMath: 0.049 ms

I am doing this adhocly running an app on iphone simulator in Release mode. I know i should probably do this in commandline/standalone, but since i plan to write this as part of an app, this may be alright.

For what I tried to do, UnsafeMutableBufferPointer seemed great, but you have to use BaseMath and all its conformances. If you are after a more general or other context. Be sure to read everything and decide which one works for you.

Comment: I don't think either `allocate(capacity:)` or the `UnsafeBufferPointer` initializer give you zeroed-out memory. I imagine some (most? all?) of the difference is due to that.

Comment: They don't; it's allocated memory, but not initialized. You need to be very thoughtful here about what you're trying to do. If performance is the concern, I would avoid allocating memory if you can help it, and instead reuse existing buffers and arrays as much as possible.

Comment: Don't worry about the unsafe-ness. This is for very fast code required doing deep learning with iOS. i should know what i am doing... ;-)

Comment: I summarized what I see in the post. if you have any doubt, let me know.

Comment: Your UnsafePointer benchmarks are cheating: every other benchmark factors in the cost of freeing the memory. Also note that they're "creating" uninitialized memory, which is significant when requesting ~40MB, because the OS probably hasn't even committed the memory to your process, and won't until you actually use it. I suspect that you'd get significantly different results if you initialized your unsafe pointer contents to something.

Comment: @zneak. You can help code review BaseMath to judge on that UnsafePointer thingy. If you find a problem, you should alert to the project author.

Comment: @kawingkelvin, I'm talking about your benchmarks, not any specific library. They are not representative of real application performance. If you're invested in the reliability of your results, these are things that you should look into. I'm not looking to sign up for more work.

Comment: @zneak. I will surly profile this. I havent explained fully the context. But I am done with this issue and need to move on. Thanks for all helpful and educative comment here.

Comment: To satisfy and not mislead, i changed "Benchmark" to just "Quick Test", and emphasize that this is not the most general context, it is specific to mine. If this proves interesting and actually work, I may write a blog about it.

Answer (score 1):

If you need performance, and know the size you need, you can use [reserveCapacity(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1538966-reservecapacity), this will preallocate the memory needed for the contents of the array. Per Apple documentation:

> If you are adding a known number of elements to an array, use this method to avoid multiple reallocations. This method ensures that the array has unique, mutable, contiguous storage, with space allocated for at least the requested number of elements.
>
> Calling the reserveCapacity(_:) method on an array with bridged storage triggers a copy to contiguous storage even if the existing storage has room to store minimumCapacity elements.
>
> For performance reasons, the size of the newly allocated storage might be greater than the requested capacity. Use the array’s capacity property to determine the size of the new storage.

Comment: Yes. i timed this var a = [Float](); a.reserveCapacity(len). Thanks.

Comment: This is 2nd only to buffer ptr alloc. I really think filling in zeros is a waste, leaving it uninitialized suit what I am doing, other cases, this can be considered unsafe and up to dev to decide.

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest thing to what I want. There's a library called BaseMath (started by Jeremy Howard), and there's a new class call AlignedStorage and UnsafeMutableBufferPointer. It is endowed with lot of math, and pretty-to-very fast too, so this reduce lot of managing of pointers while juggling math algorithm.

But this remains to be tested, this project is very new. I will leave this Q open to see if someone can suggest something better.

Note: this is the fastest in the context of what I am doing. If you really need a good struct value type Array (and variants), see other ans.